# Difference of re between go and python

Tags: python, regex, go

If we run this example with go 1.16

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?:^|_)(.)`)
fmt.Printf("%s", re.FindAll([]byte("i_love_golang_and_json_so_much"), -1))
```

the output is:

`[i _l _g _a _j _s _m]`

However, if we run it in Python3.6

```
import re
print(re.findall('(?:^|_)(.)', 'i_love_golang_and_json_so_much'))
```

the output is:

```
['i', 'l', 'g', 'a', 'j', 's', 'm']
```

The output of go has a leading `_` before each match group.

Since `?:`  is for non capturing group, it seems the result from Python is more reasonable?

Why the result from go carries a leading `_`?

Is there a way to get the same output as Python(without leading `_`) with go?

Comment: FindAll returns the *matches* not the captured *submatches*. Use FindAllSubmatch and extract the submatches to get the same result as python. https://go.dev/play/p/mGA8YIc3GKO

Comment: The return value for [Python's findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) depends on the number of capturing groups in the pattern.  If there is is exactly one group in the pattern, then findall returns that group. The Go FindAll returns the entire match.   Use FindAllSubmatch per previous comment.

Comment: For a start (and for a better question), make the strings you're matching the same.

Comment: @mkopriva It works, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Cerise Limón, Your comment makes it more clear, thank you very much!